# Why is MVC query parameter being used for the wrong variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with all my controller endpoints, whenever I use `sort` and `filter` as `query` parameter in a way similar to this example:

```cs
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet, 
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("{tenantId}/archive/retrievals", Name = "getRetrievalList")]
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RetrievalListResult> GetRetrievalList([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromQuery] int? limit = null, [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromQuery] int? offset = null, [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromQuery] System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> sort = null, [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromQuery] System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> filter = null)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It works perfectly fine with these calls:

- `{{baseUrl}}/:tenantId/archive/retrievals?filter[fields]=Text 01`
- `{{baseUrl}}/:tenantId/archive/retrievals?sort=name&filter[fields]=Text 01`

But when I only use sort…

```
{{baseUrl}}/:tenantId/archive/retrievals?sort=name
```

...then suddenly both `sort` and `filter` variables are filled, creating a false filter parameter.

Any solutions for that?

P.S. using only `filter=id` results in none of the variables being filled which is as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Dictionary** targets, **model binding** looks for matches to **parameter_name or property_name**. If no match is found, it looks for **one of the supported formats without the prefix**.

- In other words, "**sort=name**" **matches** the **format** of the supported target parameter **Dictionary<string, string> named filter**.
- Therefore, it will also be **automatically bound to the filter**.

You can **specify the prefix** to solve the problem.

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(
    [FromQuery] int? limit = null,
    [FromQuery] int? offset = null,
    [FromQuery] IEnumerable<string> sort = null,
    [FromQuery][Bind(Prefix = "filter")]IDictionary<string, string> filter = null
    )
```

[image]

Comment: So it finds the "sort" by name, adds the item to the list, and then continues to add it to the dictionary, because it matches based on the format, even though it already found a match? I don't really understand why it would do it this way.